# Entity FrameWork How to update list record

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions, updates

i have list object and try to check and update these items in that list here is my code :

```
using (var uow = new WareHouseUnitOfWork(WareHouseConnection))
{
  foreach (var item in lData)
  {
    if (uow.UsageSessionWareHouseRepository.Contains(x => x.RadAcctRefId == item.RadAcctRefId))
    {
      uow.UsageSessionWareHouseRepository.Context.Entry(item);
      uow.UsageSessionWareHouseRepository.DbSet.Attach(item);
      uow.UsageSessionWareHouseRepository.Context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
    else
    {
      uow.UsageSessionWareHouseRepository.DbSet.Add(item);
    }
  }

  session.SessionStatus = "Processed";
  var entry = uow.SessionWareHouseRepository.Context.Entry(session);
  uow.SessionWareHouseRepository.DbSet.Attach(session);
  entry.State = EntityState.Modified;

  uow.Save();
  }
```

in first loop everthing is fine but in the next i get an error :

> Attaching an entity of type 'DataRetention.Core.DataEntities.WareHouseEntites.UsageSessionWareHouse' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

I don't know how to Update like DbSet.Add(item).

Answer (score 0):

Once you find the record you can edit that directly , you don't have to do attach again or EntryState.modified as that will be tracked already for you

Comment: so i need to find the record and assign what value i want to update for each object is that correct?